# Possible to use the Microsoft Kinect with .NET Gadgeteer?

Tags: kinect, .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

Based on what's public, is it possible that someone can interact with the Kinect with the [.NET Gadgeteer](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/default.aspx)?

What (if anything) probably needs to be done to the [drivers](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/10/primesense-releases-open-source-drivers-middleware-for-kinect/)?

If you're interested, [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Clint/NET-Gadgeteer) is a Channel9 video that shows you how to use VS2010 to create an embedded application. It is due to release in Spring of 2011.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't officially released any Kinect API or drivers, though open source drivers have been implemented (just not for .NET). So I doubt that right now you'd be able to use it, especially since Gadgeteer seems to be limited to the components in its kit. You might be able to use the drivers along with the USB component of the kit (if there is one) to make something work.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use Kinect on the .NET microframe, which is the embedded CLR that powers .NET gadgeteer. You could however connect to the Kinect via a TCP Socket connections, which would be supported in gadgeteer (assuming you have a network connection) and the full .NET stack. Using the sockets you could pass the data back and forth you need. 
From experience you want to pass as little information down this pipe as possible, so if you can look for something gesture controlled I would suggest you calculate this at the service end, and simply pass an event flag down the socket.

Comment: Just to extend this I would also note the considerable work already done with http://kinectservice.codeplex.com/ This gives you everything you need to stream Kinect data to any device.